# Delphi Error creating form: Error reading PastMovesGrid.OnClick: Property OnClick does not exist

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Migrating a project from Delphi XE7 to 10.3 Rio.

Delphi Rio gives this error:

```
Error creating form:
Error reading PastMovesGrid.OnClick: Property OnClick does not exist.
```

PastMovesGrid is a TStringGrid.
Sure enough, OnClick is no longer part of TStringGrid in the latest FMX.

I've opened the DFM for the form and there is no reference to OnClick for the PastMovesGrid.

When I tell Delphi to Ignore the missing property, the form does open, but when I run the app I get a runtime error about the "Property OnClick does not exist."

I get the same results with Delphi 10.2.3.

How do I get Delphi 10.3 to forget about this missing property?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I had to do.

I opened the project in XE7 and removed all handlers for all of the TStringGrids and TGrids. Then I could open the project in Delphi Rio 10.3 and add the code into the new methods that handle clicks in TStringGrids and TGrids.